# Reaching the gamma function from the Taylor series for $e^x$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, factorial, gamma-function, eulers-number-e

The gamma function is expressed as $n! =\Gamma(n+1)= \int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}dx$

which reminds me of the Taylor series for $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Unmathematically, this makes the gamma function make sense to me: you're effectively doing a 'rearrangment' to get $n!$ However, if I am right about my intuition, I'm feeling particularly foolish about it, as I can't for the life of me properly explain what is precisely going on to get you from one to the other.

So, to you more experienced mathematicians out there, am I correct about my intuition, and if so, could I possibly trouble you to tell me exactly how you get from the Taylor series to the gamma function?

Comment: By Cauchy's formula, $$
\frac{1}{{n!}} = \frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\oint_{(0 + )} {e^t t^{ - n - 1} dt} .
$$ You can expand the contour of integration to an infinite loop around the negative axis (Hankel-type contour). After collapsing the contour on the negative axis, employing the reflection formula for the gamma function, you will arrive at Euler's integral for $n!$.

Comment: The Gamma integral is easily computed by integration by parts.

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3917532

Comment: @Gary would you mind me asking you to provide a slightly more in-depth explanation of your answer?

Comment: Alright, so after a little digging, I'm lead to believe that you can get from one to the other using Laplace transforms. I've put writing out the proper answer on my todo list, and will happily post it unless someone does something similar before me.

Comment: @ArmelFrançois Here is a detailed derivation: https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/md327/fcm_3.pdf

Answer (score 4):

It is true that on one hand,

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}e^{-x}dx=1$$ and on the other

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}e^{-x}=1.$$

But the integral is on $x$, while the sum is on $n$, and I just see a coincidence here.

---

You can modify the argument of the exponential to ensure convergence and establish for $s>1$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}e^{-sx}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty s^{1-n}=\frac1{s-1}=\int_0^\infty e^{(1-s)x}dx=\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}e^{-sx}dx.$$

Comment: (+1) It is just coincidence.

Comment: Perhaps you're right about it being coincidence. The potential (pseudomathematical) explanation I had in mind was the along the lines of the fact that for every $x$ you have a corresponding $n!$ sum, and that you only need to go from $0$ to $\infty$ because of the way $x$ and $-x$ are used that leads the formula to encompass all $x$ values. Effectively, you're sort of doing $x^n(\frac{n!}{x^n})$ to give $n!$

Comment: It is hard to say if this is just coincidence unless we know the general solution to the equation system $\sum a_n x^n=\frac1{f(x)}$, $\int x^n f(x) dx=\frac1{a_n}$.

Comment: @user. Right. With $f(x)$ a unit square, $\int_0^\infty x^nf(x) dx=\int_0^1 x^n dx=\frac1{n+1}$. But $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n=\frac1{(x-1)^2}$ so it does not work with any function.

Comment: @user: by the way, the inverse coefficients of an entire series are not known to be given by the integral of $x^n$ over the function it defines, $$\dfrac1{a_n}=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^n}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx_k}dx\ ?$$

Comment: It is an interesting question. Certainly not in a general case. Also the function should tend to infinity rather strong  to ensure convergence.

Comment: @user: not in a general case = coincidence.